# Smart Map - displaying pin in center of zip code

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I have addresses in my structure using the smart map address zip field. The Smart Map plugin looks up the Lat/Long just fine and checking independently the values seem to be correct. If I enter anything less than a full address (street, city, state, zip) even though the lat/long is there the map does not display properly, I either get a map of the world or a blue box.

I am a noobie so I am sure it is something I have not done correctly.

Example:

> Zip: 90210
>
> Lat: 34.10300320
>
> Long: -118.41046840

Code:

```
    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('groups').limit(5).find() %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }} , {{ entry.address }}, {{ craft.smartMap.img(entry.address) }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

When I click drag:
[image: Living large in Beverly Hills...]

When the map renders:
[image: Lost in the big wide world...]

Comment: Are you certain that the "Latitude" and "Longitude" values are filled in? Those should be the only critical subfields in terms of showing a pin on a map.

Comment: Yes. I get the with the lookup function (which is very nice).

Comment: Can you take a look at the `src` being generated for that image tag? The coordinates should appear in both the "markers" and "center" parameters... Something like this: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?visual_refresh=true&key=XXXXXX&scale=2&center=34.10300320,-118.410468400&size=360x240&maptype=roadmap&zoom=5&markers=color:red%7C34.10300320,-118.41046840`.

Comment: No locations in the source. The coordinates are definitely in the entry.

The parameters after the question mark:

visual_refresh=true&amp;key=AIzaSyCUIWsZPc_YqDeVdXBJD9bO6CMqcrPF-UA&amp;scale=2&amp;center=0,0&amp;size=200x150&amp;maptype=roadmap"

Comment: Very strange. I can't think of anything that would cause this, assuming the address actually contains coordinates. Ping me on [Craft Slack](https://craftcms.com/community#slack), and I'll help you troubleshoot it directly.